# Clever way to avoid for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, optimization, refactoring, vectorization

I have a data file that follows roughly this format:

```
HEADER:001,v1,v2,v3...,v10
v1,v2,v3,STATUS,v5...v6
.
.
.
HEADER:006,v1,v2,v3...v10
HEADER:012,v1,v2,v3...v10
v1,v2,v3,STATUS,v5...v6
v1,v2,v3,STATUS,v5...v6
.
.
.
etc
```

where each block or chunk of data leads off with a comma separated line that includes the header and a unique (not necessarily sequential) number, and then there *may be* 0 or more lines that are identified by the STATUS keyword in the body of the chunk.

I am reading this block in using `readLines` and then splitting it into header lines and status lines to be read in as CSV separately, since they have a different number of variables:

```
datablocks <- readLines(filename, skipNul = T)

headers <- datablocks[grepl("HEADER", datablocks, useBytes = T)]
headers <- read.csv(text=headers, header= F, stringsAsFactors = F)

statuses <- datablocks[grepl("STATUS", datablocks, useBytes = T)]
statuses <- read.csv(text=statuses, header= F, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Eventually, I would like to inner join this data, so that the variables from the header are included in each status line:

```
 all <- headers %>% inner_join(statuses, by = c("ID" = "ID"))
```

But I need a way to add the unique ID of the header to each status line below it, until the next header. The only way I can think of doing this is with a for loop that runs over the initial full text datablock:

```
header_id <- NA
for(i in seq(1:length(datablocks))) {
  is_header_line <- str_extract(datablocks[i], "HEADER:([^,]*)")
  if(!is.na(is_header_line)) {
    header_id <- is_header_line
  }
  datablocks[i] <- paste(datablocks[i], header_id, sep=",")
}
```

This works fine, but it's ugly, and not very... R-ish. I can't think of a way to vectorize this operation, since it needs to keep an external variable.

Am I missing something obvious here?

**Edit**

If the input looks literally like this

```
HEADER:001,a0,b0,c0,d0
e0,f0,g0,STATUS,h0,i0,j0,k0,l0,m0
HEADER:006,a1,b1,c1,d1
HEADER:012,a2,b2,c2,d2
e1,f1,g1,STATUS,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1
e2,f2,g2,STATUS,h2,i2,j2,k2,l2,m2
```

The output should look like this:

```
e0,f0,g0,h0,i0,j0,k0,l0,m0,a0,b0,c0,d0,001
e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1,a2,b2,c2,d2,012
e2,f2,g2,h2,i2,j2,k2,l2,m2,a2,b2,c2,d2,012
```

So there needs to be a column propagated from the parent (HEADER) to the children (STATUS) to inner join on.

Comment: Is the example at the top a fair representation of your data, e.g with the `...`?

Comment: Can you show what the output is supposed to look like?

Comment: The ... indicates that there are more columns (sorry, this probably made the example overly complicated), and the vertical . . . indicates that there are unknown number of rows. The final result should be all the status rows, with the parent header inner joined, that is, effectively each status row should have the contents of the parent row appended to it. The header row is not a header in the sense of a csv, it's the first row of a data block that has child rows (the status rows) nested within its scope.

Comment: @grosa you can use dput() to copy your dataset and paste into your question.  It will make it easier for other to understand your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
Thanks for the clarification. The specific input and output makes it dramatically easier to avoid misunderstandings.

Here I use `tidyr::separate` to separate out the header label from the "a0,b0,c0,d0" part, and `tidyr::fill` to propagate header info down into the following status rows.

```
library(tidyverse)
read_table(col_names = "text",
         "HEADER:001,a0,b0,c0,d0
         e0,f0,g0,STATUS,h0,i0,j0,k0,l0,m0
         HEADER:006,a1,b1,c1,d1
         HEADER:012,a2,b2,c2,d2
         e1,f1,g1,STATUS,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1
         e2,f2,g2,STATUS,h2,i2,j2,k2,l2,m2") %>%

mutate(status_row = str_detect(text, "STATUS"),
       header_row = str_detect(text, "HEADER"),
       header = if_else(header_row, str_remove(text, "HEADER:"), NA_character_)) %>%
  separate(header, c("header", "stub"), sep = ",", extra = "merge") %>%
  fill(header, stub) %>%
  filter(status_row) %>%
  mutate(output = paste(str_remove(text, "STATUS,"), stub, header, sep = ",")) %>%
  select(output)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  output                                    
  <chr>                                     
1 e0,f0,g0,h0,i0,j0,k0,l0,m0,a0,b0,c0,d0,001
2 e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1,a2,b2,c2,d2,012
3 e2,f2,g2,h2,i2,j2,k2,l2,m2,a2,b2,c2,d2,012
```